# Solve for $x$, $x+\sqrt{a+\sqrt{x}}=a,$ where $a>1 $

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Solve for $x$, $x+\sqrt{a+\sqrt{x}}=a,$ where $a>1$

How to approach this problem. I am putting $t=\sqrt{x}$, but it does not seem to work as it converts it into a fourth degree equation .

Any hint please would be greatly appreciated.

**Thanks!**

Comment: What about the factorization of a quartic ?

Comment: You can view it as quadratic equation in $a$, which factorizes into the product of two linear factors, namely $(a-t^2+t)(a-t^2-t-1)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your idea is not bad $t=\sqrt{x}\geq 0$ then we get $$(a-t^2)^2=a+t$$ so $$a^2-a(2t^2+1) +t^4-t=0$$

Now solving on $a$ we get the discriminat $D = (2t+1)^2$ so $$a_{1,2}= {2t^2+1\pm (2t+1)\over 2}$$

So you have to solve two quadratic equations:

- $t^2+t+1=a$
- $t^2-t=a$

Comment: Hi. How have you been?

Answer (score 0):

> $x+\sqrt{a+\sqrt{x}}=a$

$$\sqrt{a+\sqrt{x}}=a-x$$

square it

$$a+\sqrt{x}=a^2-2ax+x^2$$
move terms

$$\sqrt{x}=a^2-2ax+x^2-a$$

square again

$$x=(a^2-2ax+x^2-a)^2$$

now it is converted to a fourth degree polynomial equation, which can be factorized as

$$(a^2 - x - 2 a x + x^2) (1 - 2 a + a^2 + x - 2 a x + x^2)=0$$

Comment: Yes, I add the factorization, thank you!

Comment: how to get this factors?

Comment: This answer should NOT be down-voted. The person who down-votes MUST downvote wrong answers only, otherwise write a comment under the answer.

Comment: I guess things were fine until the last step. Maybe we can solve the expression $a^2-2ax+x^2-a$ in any way instead of turning it to a 4th degree.